# Store N key value pairs

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, ethereumjs

I have a scenario where I need to store N no. of document hashes in a smart contract with some key(id). And also fetch the particular document hash by it's key. Any help on designing the structure for storing would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough version:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    mapping(uint256 => string) hashes;

    function addDoc(uint256 id, string hash) public {
        hashes[id] = hash;
    }

    function getDoc(uint256 id) public view returns(string) {
        return hashes[id];
    }
}
```

Here you can store and retrieve the hashes based on a `uint256` id. The `mapping` will store as many id<->hash values as you need.

What you should do next is change the `string` types to be something else (`bytes` of some length) and consider adding some mass-add function if you need to store multiple hashes at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This adds one key-value pair at a time, but I need to add multiple key-value pairs at the same time which will return one transaction Id. If I run a loop from front-end it will give me different Ids on each request that means I have to run a loop at contract itself?

Comment: As I already stated in the answer, you can consider adding some functionality to add multiple hashes within the same transaction. There are a lot of things you can continue with to make your contract better but I can't write you all of it.

Comment: I understand Lauri, but it would be really helpful if you can at least guide or suggest me, what could be used here for mass-adding.

Comment: Add a function which accepts a `string[]` parameter and loop over the contents to add each separate item. Or, even better, use `bytes`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/how-to-store-ipfs-hash-using-bytes