# Solidity - Read Metadata?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, nft

I have function in a smart contract that needs to know a specific value from the metadata which I will publish on IPFS. Is there a way to parse it through or to get the value from the metadata?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because it would violate the deterministic principle of a blockchain.

[More information in this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/107373/620).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use oracles to access such data. Here an example for such an oracle: https://blog.chain.link/fetch-ipfs-api-data-token-distribution/